# javascript/jquery not working after migrating website to another server

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-commerce

I have been trying really hard to get my website up and working, but for some unknown reason I am not able to get it work like the it was working before the migration.

The problem that I am facing is that Javascript/jQuery are not working on the website after migration. I have installed jquery update as well, but it still does not work. I have even tried adding same js file using preprocess_html hook, but it does not work as well.

I am using Drupal Commerce Kickstart distribtion and Kickstart theme based on Omega. Before the "products page" listing was showing buttons like this:

[image]

And now buttons are being shown like this:
[image]

Also jQuery code that was working before on the website is not working now. I have even tried changing jQuery versions in jQuery update module, but they did not help.
Any suggestions and workarounds are warmly welcome. It has been three long days and I am still unable to figure out what is causing this problem

Thank you so much.

Comment: Try with the same version of `jQuery`

Comment: The new server it's a private server?

Comment: No. The server is the same. I had to take the site offline to do some changes. But when I uploaded them back, even the older installation did not work.

Comment: How can I check that if jQuery library is even being included on the pages or not?

Comment: If you are using Firefox (install and) use Firebug plugin and if you use some other browser use it's inspector. There is an option in every inspector for checking what (JS) files are loaded on page (try F12 key to open inspector). Or just view page source and see is there a name jQuery file. However if aggregation of JS files in turned on JS inspector will be more useful.

Comment: P.S. JavaScript will also shoot out errors if any. Depending of browser you are using it may be displayed or some plugin may be needed.

Comment: MilanG I do not see any jquery tag or include in page source :/ . No Javascript on this page
I see this in firebug :
"If <script> tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct)."

Is there any other suggestions?

Comment: MilanG I have noticed that $script variable does not print anything. do you have any idea what might be the problem?  Thanks